# How can I use better formatting in Leafet Popup HTML

Tags: html, leaflet, popup

I am not a coder and am learning as I go making a leaflet me.

I am working on my PopUps and ToolTips right now.  I have a ton of markers and I want to make some basic HTML in those PopUps which I figured out how to do, however the issue I am having is that you cannot put line returns in the code for popups, so it creates an absolute mess in the code. See example below:

```
var town_Zeonica = L.marker(map.unproject([1851,2431],map.getMaxZoom()), {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup('<font size="4" color="#a86733"><b>Zeonica<b></font><br><br><font color="Black">Shops:<br><font color="Grey">Clothier, Oilpress, Brewer<br></font><br>Villages (Resource):<br><font color="Grey">Neocorys (Midlands Palfrey)<br>Alsasos (Grain)<br>Zeocorys (Grain)<table style="height: 141px; border-color: fff;" width="404"><tbody><tr><td style="width: 194px;">Village</td><td style="width: 194px;">Resource</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 194px;">Neocorys</td><td style="width: 194px;">Midlands Palfrey</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 194px;">Alsasos</td><td style="width: 194px;">Grain</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 194px;">Zeocorys</td><td style="width: 194px;">Grain</td></tr></tbody></table>', {sticky: true, opacity: 1, closeButton: false});
```

If I try to put line returns like I would in normal HTML, it will not work, see below

```
var town_Zeonica = L.marker(map.unproject([1851,2431],map.getMaxZoom()), {icon: townIcon}).bindPopup('<font size="4" color="#a86733"><b>Zeonica<b></font><br><br><font color="Black">Shops:<br><font color="Grey">Clothier, Oilpress, Brewer<br></font><br>Villages (Resource):<br><font color="Grey">Neocorys (Midlands Palfrey)<br>Alsasos (Grain)<br>Zeocorys (Grain)<table style="height: 141px; border-color: fff;" width="404">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 194px;">Village</td>
<td style="width: 194px;">Resource</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 194px;">Neocorys</td>
<td style="width: 194px;">Midlands Palfrey</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 194px;">Alsasos</td>
<td style="width: 194px;">Grain</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 194px;">Zeocorys</td>
<td style="width: 194px;">Grain</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>', {sticky: true, opacity: 1, closeButton: false});
```

Is there some way to do this where I can have nice formatting or do I just need to create it as normal then remove all the line breaks for the final code?

Thanks anyone in advance for your help as I try to learn.

Comment: Do read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String (section "Long literal strings") and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to define a variable that contain your html code. And will look in this way:

```
var popupContent = '<font size="4" color="#a86733"><b>Zeonica<b></font><br><br><font color="Black">Shops:<br><font color="Grey">Clothier, Oilpress, Brewer<br></font><br>Villages (Resource):<br><font color="Grey">Neocorys (Midlands Palfrey)<br>Alsasos (Grain)<br>Zeocorys (Grain)<table style="height: 141px; border-color: fff;" width="404"><tbody><tr><td style="width: 194px;">Village</td><td style="width: 194px;">Resource</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 194px;">Neocorys</td><td style="width: 194px;">Midlands Palfrey</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 194px;">Alsasos</td><td style="width: 194px;">Grain</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 194px;">Zeocorys</td><td style="width: 194px;">Grain</td></tr></tbody></table>';

var town_Zeonica = L.marker(map.unproject([1851,2431], map.getMaxZoom()), {
    icon: townIcon
}).bindPopup(popupContent, {
    sticky: true,
    opacity: 1,
    closeButton: false
});
```

> I extend the answer

You also can use an escape notation, addin a backslash:

```
var popupContent ='<font size="4" color="#a86733"><b>Zeonica<b></font><br><br><font color="Black">Shops:<br><font color="Grey">Clothier, Oilpress, Brewer<br></font><br>Villages (Resource):<br><font color="Grey">Neocorys (Midlands Palfrey)<br>Alsasos (Grain)<br>Zeocorys (Grain)<table style="height: 141px; border-color: fff;" width="404"> \
<tbody> \
<tr> \
<td style="width: 194px;">Village</td> \
<td style="width: 194px;">Resource</td> \
</tr> \
<tr> \
<td style="width: 194px;">Neocorys</td> \
<td style="width: 194px;">Midlands Palfrey</td> \
</tr> \
<tr> \
<td style="width: 194px;">Alsasos</td> \
<td style="width: 194px;">Grain</td> \
</tr> \
<tr> \
<td style="width: 194px;">Zeocorys</td> \
<td style="width: 194px;">Grain</td> \
</tr> \
</tbody> \
</table>';
```

Comment: I tried that, you still have to put the HTML code on one line, but it does make it a little cleaner overall.

How do you use this for 50 different labels though? You hvae to redefine var popupContent before each one correct? So adding the var popupContent line before each marker variable?

Comment: If you are going to use 50 marker and populate a personalized popup I would strongly recommend to use a Json or Geojson to display the markers on your map.

Comment: I actually played around with Json and Good Spreadsheet and it worked but then I got stuck with something. Can't remember what it was. I will have to revisit it.

I am new to all this, just learning for fun. Thanks for the help!

I think the issue I ran into with Json/Google sheet was there was one thing I couldn't figure out how to convert to Pixels (I posted about it but never figured out how)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248633/leaflet-js-latlng-to-pixels

The escape notation is perfect!

Comment: Oh and I could not figure out how to make a group control for the markers placed with the Json and/or Google Spreadsheet.

This is not working full code but see the JS part of this:
https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/5dx3ongb/#&togetherjs=cVVr22MoUE

Didn't know how to add a group control for the markers called via the google spreadsheet.

Comment: Ugh wrong link..I really stink at using stack overflow (I am new to it, and JSFiddle..and well, all of this :)

https://jsfiddle.net/k5nr6x37/

I could not figure out how to add layer groups for the data pulled with tabletop